# Preserve HTML (<p>,<class>) inside a php echo

Tags: php, html, echo, kml, preserve

how can i make an echo, preserve html information, and make a while from a query? i want to generate an kml file with mysql data. here is what i've done:

```
echo '<xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"></br>';
echo '<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\" xmlns:gx=\"http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2\" xmlns:kml=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"></br>';
echo '<Document></br>';

echo '<Placemark id='.$row['id'].' ></br>';
echo ' <name>'.$row['icao'].'</name></br>';
echo '  <description>'.$row['name'].'</description></br>';
echo '   <Point></br>';
echo '    <coordinates>'.$row['lat'].','.$row['lon'].'</coordinates></br>';
echo '   </Point></br>';
echo '</Placemark></br>';

echo '</Document></br>';
echo '</kml>';
```

The result should be this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<Placemark id='id'>
  <name>'icao'</name>
    <description>'name'</description>
      <Point>
       <coordinates>'lat','lon'</coordinates>
      </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

But i got that:

```
id icao name lat lon id icao name lat lon id icao name lat lon
```

So, how can i retain the kml tags `(<Placemark>, <Document>, <kml>, ...)`, inside an php echo?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`. Don't forget to pass the first three parameters, especially the correct encoding. Not `htmlentities`, that one does more than you need to do.

Comment: should be <`?`xml version...

Comment: Be careful of the order of your coordinates.  KML is [longitude, latitude, and (optional) altitude.](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates).

Comment: Jan and geocode, thanks! Saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlentities(); in php, like so:

```
echo htmlentities($data);
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php